# Android App stuck for a few seconds while generating list of informations with images

Tags: android, sqlite, file, titanium, appcelerator

I made an Android App with Titanium Appcelerator where you can search for products in a local SQLite database. The list I generate when the user clicks "Show all" takes the first 50 entries and displays the info as a list. All works fine as long as i have no images. When I include the images to the app (about > 10.000 images in a folder), the app is stuck the first time I make a database request and generate the listview.

If I go back and repeat the step, it will work immediately. If I restart the app it will stuck. I don't know how to fix that. Could it be, that one folder with thousands of files is the problem? Could it help to split the images into different folders?

I create the window and send data to it, before I open it

```
if (!onlineSearchContainerWindow) {
    var onlineSearchContainerWindow = SearchWindow();
}
onlineSearchContainerWindow.fireEvent('setDataArr', {
    first : self.first
});
onlineSearchContainerWindow.open();
```

I had a Template for the Listview with a imageview included

```
                childTemplates : [{
                    type : 'Ti.UI.View',
                    bindId : 'artPicContainer',
                    properties : {
                        left : '0dp',
                        width : Number((dpuDeviceWidth / 2) - 25) + 'dp',
                        height : Number((dpuDeviceWidth / 2) - 25) + 'dp',
                        borderWidth : 2,
                        borderColor : '#6c6c6c',
                        borderRadius : 4,
                        backgroundColor : '#fff'
                    },
                    childTemplates : [{
                        type : 'Ti.UI.ImageView', // artPic ICON
                        bindId : 'artPic',
                        properties : {
                            isLoaded : true,
                            size : {
                                width : Number((dpuDeviceWidth / 2) - 25) + 'dp',
                                height : Number((dpuDeviceWidth / 2) - 25) + 'dp',
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                },
```

I open the database, execute the statement with a limit of 50

```
db = Titanium.Database.open("productsDB");
var dbData = db.execute(statement + " LIMIT " + String(number * maxDisplay) + ", " + Number(maxDisplay + 1));
```

Then I create a data object with the image path for id artPic and other values and push it into an array

```
var listviewData = {
            firstLevelContainer : {
                artikelnummer : xxx,
            },
            artNrLabel : {
                text : xxx
            },
            artPic : {
                image : "/images/path/" + imagename + ".jpg"
            }
        };
```

I create a Listviewsection and link the array with the datasets. Then I create the Listview and set the template and the section

```
   itemListView = Ti.UI.createListView({
            top : 0,
            templates : {
                'template' : myTemplate
            },
            defaultItemTemplate : 'template',
            footerView : endRow,
            sections : [itemListSection],
        });
        mainCon.add(itemListView);
```

After that I hide the preloader for the window. But till then, the Preloader stucks for a long time, stop turn around an freezing.

I dont link the building process to the open event.

The image size is around 1-3 kb each.
All together:
[image]

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Can you share the code of loading the images and also are you specifying the classname property for each of the row for reuse?

Comment: How big are the images? Are you starting the request when the window is open (inside the `open` event or after that) so it won't block the UI (display a loading indicator helps). Are you creating an array and use setItems(array) to fill the listview?

Comment: Provided the code above. The images are round 1-3 KB

Answer (score 0):

According to the information that you have provided their can be two possibilities causing delay of action :

> 1. You are saving the image files in the SQLite database

**Solution :** If this is the case then try saving the Image URL in the database and not the images. You can get the image URL by using the `FileSystem` API.

> 2. Your Database is Installed when you click on the 'Show All' button

**Solution :** If this is the case then remove the `install` method from the eventListener and place it in the alloy.js or index.js, this would help you speed up the process when you click on the 'Show All' button.

**Good Luck & Cheers**

Ashish Sebastian

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already have the URL in the database and already installed the database in a previous window.